# Multiple Armature Tips to single Armature Root?

Tags: armature, parent

Is it possible to take 2 armature ***TIPS***

[image]

and connect them to a third armature ***ROOT***?

[image]

BLENDER 2.77 (If possible in previous version I'd like to know)

If not possible, anything that mimics that result would be appreciated.

Comment: There are ways to do things like this, but each case requires something different. The important question to ask is, what is the final result you are looking for? Which bone would you move to control the bunch? Would you move the third bone and the end of the other two follow? Or would you move one of the other two, making the third and second bone follow (vise versa for the second bone)? Or something entirely different. Blender does not support this exact type of thing because questions come up to which bone has the control. Depending on your answer to that, you use a certain method.

Comment: For the sake of clarity the first two  (A)(B) are already parented to the rest of the visible structure.... The third (C) would have to be the child of both. A and B would essentially be your collarbones and C would be your Sternum. (The large one in the back would be the SPINE. And I could just keep it simple and limit it to the spine, but I want to see WHAT is possible)

Comment: Well, from what I know, having a bone connected to two others is impossible. I would use an empty with hooking or something similar to make a "weighted average" where both bones control some of their meeting position, or just use an empty to control where they end if you are placing them relative to the third bone (C). In your case (a body), I would keep everything as you have it, and parent the Sternum to the backbone as you said. I hope you understand what I'm saying when I tell you that having two connected bones would produce conflict over which to follow.

Comment: In a real body, I think the sternum would be parented (keep offset) to the spine, and the collar bones would have their ends stretched to the shoulders and the collar bone. So use a constraint to lock the collar bones to the shoulders, then use a "stretch to" constraint to the sternum